# Split String into Parts Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am a new programmer and I want to split a file name to get the date from it with regex in Laravel

```
filename: 999_20181502_api.txt
```

So i want to get the date as 20181502 or like 2018-15-02

Comment: Is the filename *always* in that format? Some digits, then an underscore, then the date, then an underscore, then a string?

Comment: Have you done any research at all into the various string manipulation functions?

Comment: @Qirel yes always in this format

Comment: Then use `explode('_', $filename)` and use the second element.

Comment: "for some reasons i want it with regexp"  And what exactly are those reasons?  If they're not _good_ reasons, then why overcomplicate things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern: `(?<=_)\d{8}(?=_)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wt4632/1)

Explanation:

`(?<=_)` positive lookbehind, to assert if what's preceeding is underscore

`\d{8}` - match 8 digits

`(?=_)` - assert what is following is underscore

Comment: Thank you, and one last question if i prefer to have the result like that: 2019-03-27 what should i do?

Comment: @Gavroch Use slightly diferent pattern `(?<=_)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(?=_)` and replace it with replacement pattern `\1-\2-\3`